# “Appium” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software

Tags: android-studio, automation, appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

When I'm trying to open appium on my mac, getting the error “Appium” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.

Comment: Instead of changing from Preference .Try to open appium twice by doing a mouse  right click . First time if you open appium by mouse right click, it shows error '/getting the error “Appium” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software'. Second time if you try right click it will show open button and Open option will be shown in context menu 100% this works

-Kiran

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[image]

- Go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General.
  [image]
- Click on the "open anyway" button.
- Once it's done, try to open appium again.

Answer (score 8):

[image]Instead of changing from Preference .Try to open appium twice by doing a mouse  right click . First time if you open appium by mouse right click, it shows error '/getting the error “Appium” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software'. Second time if you try right click it will show open button and Open option will be shown in context menu refer attached image

Answer (score 4):

On MacOs Ventura, the methods listed here may no longer work 
I got results by using `sudo spctl --master-disable`
After this, go to finder and ctrl+click the app
You get a prompt asking if you want to open the app
Click on open and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 2):

This is because of some security reasons in MAC os. You just have to follow these below steps:

1. Click on the Apple icon in your system.
2. Go to the System Preferences->Security Privacy-> General
3. Click on the open anyway button from the bottom
4. Run again Appium inspector
   [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFP3H.png)

Answer (score 2):

Following @kiran -Instead of changing from Preference .Try to open appium twice by doing a mouse right click . First time if you open appium by mouse right click, it shows error '/getting the error “Appium” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software'. Second time if you try right click it will show open button and Open option will be shown in context menu 100% this works

I tried the sam and it worked for me. Thank You so much Kiran

Answer (score 0):

i believe problem is in 1.22.2 version
1.20.0 starts like expected (Monterey 12.2.1)

Answer (score 0):

For Mac OS Ventura 13.5

You can follow the below step-

1. Click on the Apple icon in your system.
2. Go to the System Preferences -> Privacy & Security
3. Scroll down below security.
4. Click on the open anyway button

Answer (score 0):

For latest MacBook version ......

1. Click on the apple icon top left
2. Click on system setting
3. Click on Privacy and Security
4. Scroll down to Security -->it will show blocked application --open anyway
5. Now run the appium inspector/Appium again