# Getting error while running Appium on Mac

Tags: appium

Getting below error while running Appium

Encountered internal error running command: Error: Cannot verify the signature of '/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-server/apks/appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.24.0.apk'. Original error: The JAVA_HOME location '$(/usr/libexec/java_home)' must exist

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Duplicate of this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68157955/appium-can-t-be-opened-because-apple-cannot-check-it-for-malicious-software

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error a while ago, try using this on terminal.

```
 xattr -cr "/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app"
 codesign --deep --sign - /Applications/Appium\ Server\ GUI.app
```

it should solve the error, it did for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Worked for me. (I don't know why you need more documentation. Has the Bot looked at other SO answers?)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I could open it only from the console.

```
open /Applications/Appium\ Server\ GUI.app
```